# EDI integration with odoo v8

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, edi

I want to process order from some sftp location. Please help me.
I checked base 'edi' module is nothing have any information like how to enter FTP details or location.
Please help me on this|
Thanks,
Sonu

Comment: Please share more details about EDI integration.

Comment: I have a vendor central account, from daily basis geeting shipments from vendor central by mail and then our team creating orders. But now i want to orders automatically create using EDI...

Comment: There is one application available in Odoo apps store, may it will help you for this
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/amazon_vendor_central_ept/

Comment: Im using odoo v8, and also the price is also too much. i want to make my own, just need some help how to start with this